# web.xml configuration as annotations

Tags: java, xml, servlets, configuration, annotations

I am trying to start a basic example project that uses Vaadin together with Spring. How can I put such xml configuration:

```
 <context-param>
      <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
      <param-value>
        org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
      </param-value>
    </context-param>

   <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>com.app.config.AppConfig</param-value>
   </context-param>

   <listener>
     <listener-class>
       org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
     </listener-class>
   </listener>
```

to such java based configuration:

```
    @WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = MyVaadinUI.class,       widgetset = "com.rrd.mavenproject1.AppWidgetSet")
public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. If you had a custom Servlet `XxxListener`, you could annotate it with `@WebListener`. In this case you are trying to load `ContextLoaderListener` which you have no control over.

Context parameters are global to the application and therefore can't be added to one single `@WebServlet` annotation.

What you might be looking for is the Servlet API's [`ServletContainerInitializer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer.html) or Spring's [`WebApplicationInitializer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html) to perform Java configuration.

In either of these, you will have access to the [`ServletContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) where you can [add context parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#setInitParameter%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) and [listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#addListener%28java.lang.Class%29). The strength of these classes is that you can create your Servlets, Filters, and Listeners from a Spring context.